# BC4J - How-To needed

Tags: java, servlets, bc4j

I'm working on an old `Java` project which uses `BC4J` and runs on `JBOSS`, currently it has only on JSP-Pages. 
As I understood all starts with the following code in a JSP accordingly to a definition in a `*.cpx` file:

```
<jbo:ApplicationModule id="MyModuleAm" definition="MY.MyModule" releasemode="Stateful" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding='windows-1252'?>
<!DOCTYPE JboProject SYSTEM "jbo_03_01.dtd">
<!--BC4J Client Data Model-->

<JboProject
   Name="MY"
   Package="" >
   <Session
      Name="MyModule"
      Package="....my.package"
      Configuration="MyModuleLocal" >
   </Session>
</JboProject>
```

This allows me to call the module as follows:

```
MyModuleImpl myModule =(MyModuleImpl)MyModuleAm.useApplicationModule();
```

I have to create servlets, which use the `BC4J`. I searched on the web but I was not able to find an example, found only the `API` which is not enough.

Any hints?